# rest client in nuxeo automation chains

Tags: rest, nuxeo

I am thinking to develop a custom Operation to be executed in an automation chain that needs to execute calls to external rest services.

I do not want to add dependencies if not necessary and before starting to use one of the many java implementations available, I would like to know if there is a library that Nuxeo itself already uses.
I know that CXF is used in Nuxeo but I do not think that the library for rest clients is already a dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nuxeo already uses Apache Commons HttpClient 3.1, Apache HttpComponents 4.3.3 and Jersey 1.17, any of which can be used to make REST client calls. There are probably others you can use, just look at the dependencies in the [master POM](https://github.com/nuxeo/nuxeo/blob/release-6.0/pom.xml#L1450) to see if your favorite library is here.

Answer (score 1):

All third-party libraries used by Nuxeo are listed in [the `dependencyManagement` section of the Nuxeo root POM `org.nuxeo:nuxeo-ecm`](https://github.com/nuxeo/nuxeo/blob/master/pom.xml#L1415).

You should indeed make your choice picking in that list first, if it contains a library fulfilling your needs.